# Called local class with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a small issue with node and calling a local class in another file from app.js,

For example

**foo.js**

```
class bar{
    constructor(){
    }
}
modules.export = bar;
```

And then in **app.js** I have

```
var foo = require('./foo');
var fooClass = new bar();
```

But it throws an error saying `bar` is undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: javascript is case sensitive

Comment: I understand that, thats why I require foo and named the class FOO

Comment: you cant use `new FOO();` FOO is not defined, instead try `var fooClass = new foo();`

Comment: @pig__man your logic is beyond me

Comment: Fixed the casing so its easier to understand

Comment: The answers and comments still apply. `bar` is undefined in `app.js`, use `new foo();`.

Comment: you've introduced several more typos into the question instead... can you just post the actual code?

Comment: Yeah Thanks Paul, its my first project with Node. The example I was following was using: 
var foo = require('foo');
var bar = new foo();
So I thought bar was reference the class inside foo.js not the local variable foo. That's my bad

Comment: No worries, I've seen that catch lots of new node users. The way I remember it is that when you set `var foo = require(./foo)`, you now have a variable `foo` which points to the class `bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `module.exports`, not `modules.export`.

Also check how you're importing. When you use `var foo = require('./foo');`, you must also use `var fooClass = new foo()`. The local variable / class will match the name you gave it when you `required` it, *not* the name you gave it when you defined it in the original file.

For example, the following would also work:

```
var Bar = require('./foo');
var bar = new Bar();
```

You can label your variables whatever you want when you import / require them, regardless of their names when you declare them -- including classes.

Comment: To be honest I can't recall which one I used. I had a few methods that where working properly when I exported and then I wrapped them into a class to make it neater and exported the class now it's throwing undefined.

Comment: You probably had `module.exports` in your actual code. I just tried it with `modules.export`, and got the expected `ReferenceError: modules is not defined`.

Comment: Oh that is most likely the error. I was reference another example and forgot what I named my require. Thanks for the help